# How do i convert the phantom mnemonic

Tags: phantom, javascript, web3.js

How to convert a mnemonic from phantom i.e: 'some words that are secret ...'

Into the following format:
[
118, 72, 137, 65, 79, 174, 185, 29, 222, 164, 107, 111, 226, 137, 150, 19,
162, 10, 56, 231, 5, 12, 169, 177, 42, 0, 165, 106, 147, 126, 238, 169, 37,
421, 10, 94, 94, 12, 207, 208, 86, 225, 92, 66, 252, 152, 161, 236, 44, 184,
7, 214, 31, 17, 133, 161, 49, 46, 166, 35, 197, 106, 0, 8,
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get is using this method:

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as bip39 from "bip39";

(async () => {
  const mnemonic =
    "pill tomorrow foster begin walnut borrow virtual kick shift mutual shoe scatter";
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic, ""); // (mnemonic, password)
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(seed.slice(0, 32));
  console.log(`${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`); // 5ZWj7a1f8tWkjBESHKgrLmXshuXxqeY9SYcfbshpAqPG
  console.log(`Private key: [${keypair.secretKey.toString()}]`);
})();
```

[source](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way if you're just doing a handful of conversions is to just import the mnemonic to Solflare, then export the private keys.

Solflare exports private keys as UInt8Array format (the same as keypair), while Phantom does not.

Alternatively, you can also just export the individual accounts from Phantom via private key, and import them to Solflare, and finally export as UInt8Array.

Answer (score -1):

You can't convert a mnemonic into a UInt8Array private key.